# arm7 eeror in iphone opencv project

Tags: iphone

How to solve ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice: /Users/admin/Downloads/FaceDetect/libcv.a for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error in iphone opencv project

Comment: Please be more specific. It is not very clear to me what your problem is!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the architecture armv7.

[image]

and change the compiler GCC to LLVM.

[image]